# jQuery - Hide button/link if div is empty

Tags: jquery

Be gentle, still learning but what is wrong with my code, I need to look inside each container div, see if a certain div is empty and remove the link/button.

```
$('.eventText').each( function () {
if( $('.exPanel').is(':empty') ) {
        $('a.eventLink').hide();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/o57c47cx/2/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of considerations here...

The first is that an element isn't `:empty` if it contains line breaks in some browsers, so you might want to look inside.

I have also used the context to only look for the elements within the current match, rather than looking for all of them.

```
$('.eventText').each( function () {
  console.log($('.exPanel', this));

  if(!$.trim($('.exPanel', this).html())) {
      $('a.eventLink', this).hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `.exPanel` isn't empty. You should add more code to trim the whitespace using jQuery's `trim()`

```
if ($.trim($('.exPanel').html().length) < 1) {
    $('a.eventLink').hide();
}
```

or

```
if (!$.trim($('.exPanel').html().length)) {
    $('a.eventLink').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
if ( $('.exPanel').children().length < 1 ) {
     // do something
}
```

The `children()` function returns a JQuery object that contains the children. So you just need to check the size and see if it has less than one child, equals to **no children**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.eventText .exPanel').each(function(){
  if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
    $(this).siblings('a.eventLink').hide();
  } 
});
```